# Exposing Kibana behind GCE ingress (UNHEALTHY state)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, elastic-cloud

I'm trying to expose Kibana behind of a GCE ingress, but the ingress is reporting the kibana service as `UNHEALTHY` while it is `healthy and ready`. Just note that the healthcheck created by the Ingress is still using the default value `HTTP` on the root `/` and `Port`: `ex:32021`.
Changing the healthcheck in GCP console to `HTTPS` on `/login` and `Port: 5601` doesn't change anything and the service is still reported as `Unhealthy`. The healthcheck port is also being overwritten to the original value, which is strange.
I'm using `ECK 1.3.1` and below are my configs. I'm I missing anything? Thank you in advance.

```yaml
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: d3m0
spec:
  version: 7.10.1
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 1
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
---
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: d3m0
spec:
  version: 7.10.1
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: d3m0
  podTemplate:
    metadata:
      labels:
        kibana: node
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 1Gi
            cpu: 1
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            scheme: HTTPS
            path: "/login"
            port: 5601
  http:
    service:
      spec:
        type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kibana-ingress
spec:
  backend:
      serviceName: d3m0-kb-http
      servicePort: 5601
```

Comment: HTTP expect a 200 OK response, if there's a redirect like 301 will be marked as UNHEALTHY. If you change the HC to TCP, does it work?

Comment: Hi @ArnauSenserrich, thank you for commenting. Here the Ingress backend services can only receive HTTPS traffic from the healthcheck probs because they are fully configured on the Best Security practices by ECK. The default Healthcheck of the ingress as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#def_inf_hc) is using HTTP on the nodeport which automatically fails. I managed to make a working fix for now. I will publish a full functionning example when I complete all the setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using ECK, all the security feature are enabled on ES and Kibana, which means that their services do not accept HTTP traffic used by the default GCP loadbalancer Healthcheck. You must add the required annotations to the services and override the healthcheck paths as in the code below. Please find more details [here](https://github.com/elastic/cloud-on-k8s/tree/master/config/recipes/gclb).

```yaml
    apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
    kind: Kibana
    metadata:
      name: d3m0
    spec:
      version: 7.10.1
      count: 1
      elasticsearchRef:
        name: d3m0
      http:
        service:
          metadata:
            labels:
              app: kibana
            annotations:
              # Enable TLS between GCLB and the application
              cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"https":"HTTPS"}'
              service.alpha.kubernetes.io/app-protocols: '{"https":"HTTPS"}'
              # Uncomment the following line to enable container-native load balancing.
              cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
    
      podTemplate:
        metadata:
          labels:
            name: kibana-fleet
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: kibana
            resources:
              limits:
                memory: 1Gi
                cpu: 1
            readinessProbe:
                  # Override the readiness probe as GCLB reuses it for its own healthchecks
                  httpGet:
                    scheme: HTTPS
                    path: "/login"
                    port: 5601
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing **Kibana** through the helm chart:

```
helm install kibana elastic/kibana -n elastic-stack
```

Then the GCP default ingress wouldn't work. You'll have to use the `nginx-ingress` for that.

After instaling the helm chart, make sure you also have the `nginx-ingress` helm chart installed.

Then, apply this ingress configuration to enable the HTTPS

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kibana-ingress
  namespace: elastic-stack
spec:
  ingressClassName: "nginx"  # Specify NGINX Ingress Class
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - "kibana.test.com"
    secretName: cloudflare-origin-cert
  rules:
  - host: "kibana.test.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kibana-kibana
            port:
              number: 5601
```

Then, you can run `kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx` to get the **External IP** which you can use to point the DNS record to.